# TYPO3 Extbase - Correct way to add unique-constraint?

Tags: mysql, typo3, extbase

Does anybody know how to add an unique constraint to `ext_tables.sql` without creating problems like TYPO3 wanting to re-generate it every time you use the Database analyzer?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName(
  CONSTRAINT unique_iban UNIQUE (iban) 
)

CREATE TABLE tableName(
  iban varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL UNIQUE 
)
```

With both ways the database analyzer wants to create the constraints, even if they are already there.

First one additionally creates an error when you execute it:

> Error: Duplicate key name 'unique_iban'

Second one creates one new constraint every time you hit execute:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP KEY iban
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP KEY iban_2
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked (*thanks to Christian Müller*):

```
CREATE TABLE tableName(
  iban varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY iban (iban)
)
```